# Вывод изображения перевернутым

Tags: android, java, изображения

Здравствуйте!
Как в Java (Android) возможно организовать случайный вывод изображения правильно или перевернуто ?

Т.е. при нажатии экранной клавиши задается изображение в imageview, чтоб это изображение могло быть выведено правильно или в перевернутом положении ? Как это возможно организовать ?
Спасибо!

Comment: Попутный вопрос, если позволите, как сделать так чтоб изображение выводилось перевернутым или нет рэндомно ?

Comment: @Kvazios - [ideone.com][1]

[1]: http://ideone.com/ChlTgR

Comment: Спасибо!
Мне доступно к передаче только 1 очко ) Его и передал, еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rotate image in imageview by an angle](http://ideone.com/ChlTgR)